# Can I select an object in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to select an object in Unity 2D by clicking on it once. If the object is selected it follows the cursor and when the user clicks once more the object stops being selected. I don't want to use drag and drop.

Is it possible to do that and if yes do I need to use rigid body or any other component?

Comment: Do you want it to be in the game view or the scene view?

Comment: @Obscure021 I think scene view. Sorry, I am very new to Unity and I am still figuring things out. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: If Game VIew and Scene View sound confusing, Do you want the select the object in-game as a game mechanic or in the Unity Scene "Tab" to setup your level, etc.?

Comment: When you are talking about selecting an object, you are talking about selecting it in the editor or in the game?

Comment: @Obscure021 I am talking about in game. Like the player can pick an object1 and if selected the object follows the cursor in game and when the player clicks again somewhere the object1 drops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Unity [`OmMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) Event. This event is called when the user presses the mouse button over the Collider.

---

On the first click, your object will start following the mouse. You can **calculate the mouse position** using [`Input.mousePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) and then convert that to world space.

On Second Click, the object will stop following the mouse.